# C++ How to make a vector with a class type pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism

So basically I want to make a vector called

```
  vector <Employee> *EmployeeDB;
  Employee *temp;
```

and I want to put this inside

```
  temp = new Manager(first, last, salary, meetings, vacations);
  EmployeeDB->push_back(*temp);
```

oh I am using inheritance and polymorphism, which is why the new is Manager type.

P.S I forgot, The parent class is the Employee and it has 3 subclass which inherits the parents class. 3 subclass are manager, researcher and engineer class.

Comment: You can create the `vector` which holds the pointer to `Employee`, i.e., `vector<Employee*>`

Comment: I don't see a question mark. Please provide a complete minimalist verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you want to change the database type, from:

```
std::vector <Employee> *EmployeeDB;
```

this is a pointer to a vector, holding Employee instances. This means that the vector contains copies of employees, probably not what you want.

To:

```
std::vector <Employee*> EmployeeDB;
```

This is a vector instance, holding pointers to Employees.

You also should take care of ownership of the Employees. One solution could be handle it with `new` and `delete`, but the preferred one is using smart pointers:

```
std::vector <std::unique_ptr<Employee> > EmployeeDB;
```

---

Edit: In class definitions, the space mark does not matter when defining pointer objects.

Your two examples are the same: `Character* party[3]` and `Character *party[3]` mean exactly the same.

What is really important, is where the pointer mark is in templated classes definitions (inside or outside the `<>` sign in the `std::vector<>` specialization).

So, it is not the same having a [(vector) (of pointers)] (`vector <Employee*>`), than having a [(pointer to a vector) (of instances)] (`vector <Employee>*`).

Comment: omg thanks a lot, but I still dont quite get it, another example, Character* party[3] will work? but Character *party[3] will not? because the pointer is at the array not at the classtype?

Answer (score 1):

When declaring `std::vector<Employee> *EmployeeDB` you create a pointer to a vector. If you want your container to hold polymorphic types, you need to declare it like so:

```
std::vector<Employee*> EmployeeDB;
```

From now on, you can call:

```
Employee *temp = new Manager(first, last, salary, meetings, vacations);
EmployeeDB.push_back(temp);
```

EDIT:

However, much better programming practice would be using `std::shared_ptr<T>` or `std::unique_ptr<T>` instead of calling `new` (and eventually `delete`) by yourself. You can code a safer implementation by changing your declarations to:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Employee>> EmployeeDB;
```

and add elements to your vector like so:

```
auto tmp = std::make_shared<Employee>(Manager(first, last, salary, meetings, vacations))
EmployeeDB.push_back(tmp);
```

Do not forget to add `#include <memory>` for usage of `shared` and `unique` pointer wrappers.

Comment: I was editing the answer with such implementation. One second please